# Is $\hat{\theta}$ unbiased?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> The random variable $X$ has pdf $f_{\theta}(x)=\theta x^{\theta-1}, \
> > 0<x<1,$ for an unknown parameter $\theta>0.$ Assume that $x_1,...,x_n$
>   measure data from a sample on $X$.
>
> a) Compute the ML-estimator $\hat{\theta}$ of $\theta.$
>
> b) Compute $E[\ln X]$ as a function of $\theta$ if $X$ is distributed
>   according to the above.
>
> c) Is $\hat{\theta}$ unbiased?

Long story short, a) and b) I have computed to be

**a):** $$\hat{\theta}=-\frac{n}{\sum_{k=1}^n\ln{X_k}},$$

**b):** $$E[\ln X]=-\frac{1}{\theta}.$$

This is correct as far as the book. Now to the real problem. Here is what I did on c):

$\hat{\theta}$ is unbiased iff $E[\hat{\theta}]=\theta.$ Let's check if it's true. We have that

$$E[\hat{\theta}]=E\left[\frac{-n}{\sum_{k=1}^n\ln{X_k}}\right]=\frac{-n}{\sum_{k=1}^nE[\ln{X_k}]}=\frac{-n}{-\frac{n}{\theta}}=\theta.\tag1$$

Yes, it is unbiased.

**Correct answer:** No, it is not unbiased. Take for example $\theta = 1$ and $n=1$, then $\hat{\theta}=1/\ln{X}$ and

$$E[\hat{\theta}]=-E\left[\frac{1}{\ln{X}}\right]=\infty.$$

**Question:**

What is wrong with $(1)?$

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80874/expectation-of-reciprocal-of-a-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$E(\frac{1}{X})$ is generally not equal to $\frac{1}{E(X)}$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=1/x$ is strictly convex for $x>0$, so by Jensen's inequality, $E[f(X)]\ge f(E[X])$ for a positive r.v. $X$, moreover, it the inequality is strict unless $X$ is a constant. In our case,
$$
E\left[\frac{1}{\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \big(-\ln X_i\big)}\right]> \frac{1}{E\left[\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \big(-\ln X_i\big)\right]} = \theta,
$$so the estimator has a positive bias for any $n\ge 1$.